# Create enter (new line) automaticly text file in android

Tags: android, string, file

I made a *create file app* in android, I want to write a string variable to `file.txt`, and it should automatically insert an `enter` (navigate to new line)

I used:

```
public void cekFile() {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try {
        BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                "/data/log/log.txt"), true));
        if (root.canWrite()) {
            fw.write("Monitoring Panggilan" + "\n");
            fw.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("One", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It's not navigating to new line.

Comment: Please rephrase your post. Do you want to write "some" strings into text file?

Comment: i cant read your mind please rephrase your quetion please

Comment: i have reprased my post, i hope you can get it

Comment: I have a doubt you are checking the canWrite of the ExternalStorage and where writing the file in data folder ? where is this your data folder ? internal storage or ExternalStorage ?

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh,,, ohh god, i forget
thanks

Comment: so where you wan to write ? internal storage or ExternalStorage ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fw.newLine()` method before or after the `fw.write()` method.