# Writing to text file, file not updating

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I have been having some trouble: my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597215/writing-string-to-text-file) explains it all. I was trying to write to a file in the external storage which on my device is /data/media or /sdcard. The file (when you adb pull it with device on) one saves two lines of text and then gets overwritten but once you adb pull it again in recovery with /data mounted, all the logs appear.

I have tried mounting /data and then writing to the file but still no luck... Any help?

Comment: You already have a bounty on your original question. Asking yet another question on the same topic is just a waste of time.

Comment: The previous question was answered in the other post, thank you

Answer (score -2):

You code does not flush the `BufferedWriter,` so data are not written to log file but stays in the buffer.

How about replace code in try block of method 'writeToLog' of your code by following code?

```
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true))
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw); 
    out.println(text);
    bw.flush() // Explicitly flushbufferedWriter
    out.close();
```

Comment: Closing the `PrintWriter` automatically flushes it, which automatically flushes the `BufferedWriter.`

Comment: That did not work, once there is two lines of text.. it overwrites both of them. But if I pull the file through adb, it shows all of the text entries though.